# error passing in set<template T> as a parameter

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I am trying to pass a 'generic set' as a parameter.

```
template<class T>
class Printer {
public:
    static doprint (std::set < T >& ms){

        for (std::set::const itr = ms.begin(); itr!= ms.end(); ++itr)
        {
            //do processing. e.g. printing
            cout<< ms.print(); 
        }
        ms.clear();
    }
};
```

I call the method using

```
std::set <classA> setA; //both class A and B have a .print() method
std::set <classB> setB;
    // populates A & B

Printer::doPrint(setA);
Printer::doPrint(setB);
```

but I am getting the following error

```
error: 'template <class T> class Printer' used without template parameters.
```

any idea on how I can fix this ?

Comment: The error message tells you **exactly** what the problem is. (How about `Printer<classA>::doPrint(setA);`, etc.?)

Comment: ohh! that fixes the bug. I am still learning how to use templates. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the template is on the class, you have to explicitly call it out when you call doPrint:

```
Printer<classA>::doPrint(setA) ;
```

Usually to get around this, people make helper functions which can figure out the template arguments by themselves:

```
template <class T>
  void call_doprint(std::set < T >& ms) { Printer<T>::doPrint( ms) ; }
```

Then you can just call:

```
call_doprint( setA) ;
```

This is one reason people like `make_sharedptr`, and `make_pair` better than calling the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

std::set is no class just a template. So is Printer. So whenever you wish to actually use them as types you must provide the template parameters to instantiate a class.  This means std::set::const_iterator , Printer and Printer.